# When using Idea to remotely debug a project under Jetty, the prompt is :timeout during handshake

Tags: java, docker, debugging, intellij-idea, jetty

I am using Remote JVM Debug in IDEA to remotely debug my jetty project on the server with the following prompt：timeout during handshake

```
2021-12-20T03:14:04.816059981Z Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 16005
2021-12-20T03:14:05.755978464Z 2021-12-20 11:14:05.752:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1042ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2021-12-20T03:14:05.866523012Z 2021-12-20 11:14:05.865:INFO:oeju.TypeUtil:main: JVM Runtime does not support Modules
2021-12-20T03:14:06.184914262Z 2021-12-20 11:14:06.184:INFO::main: Console stderr/stdout captured to /hostfiles/logs/2021_12_20.jetty.log
2021-12-20T03:20:02.669027944Z Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake
```

The startup configuration is as follows：

```
java -server \
     -Xmx3550m \
     -Xms3550m \
     -Xmn1256m \
     -Xss228k \
     -Xdebug \
     -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=16005 \
     -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 \
     -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m \
     -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 \
     -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 \
     -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
     -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar \
     jetty.base=/hostfiles
```

Jetty is in Docker, using jdk 1.8, with the following preset parameters：

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you using as the debugger?  What jwdp connection options are you using on the debugger side?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: I don't think the language affects the sharing of knowledge, but I've updated it to English to make it better for everyone to view.

Comment: If your `${jetty.base}` configuration uses something that requires a forked JVM, this simple approach is not possible.  See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7299

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you. @Joakim Erdfelt

Answer (score 0):

The current problem is caused by the fact that the forked JVM in Jetty is not configured efficiently.

See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7299